# XMPP / Jingle Voice Library for Android

Tags: android, xmpp, libjingle

I'm looking for a Jingle library (or app code) that exists on android and supports Voice for Gtalk or any xmpp in general.
I don't really want to write JNI for libjingle. I would prefer something in java /android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no java port for it. Its better to use the libjingle c .so and use JNI on android.

Answer (score 1):

Check this repo it should help.
[webrtc-jingle-client](https://github.com/lukeweber/webrtc-jingle-client)